# How to use google adsense on local host ? Also do not have a google adsense account

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, adsense

I've been searching the internet for the last 2 days and everywhere I got was:

> Add this line in the script , `google_adtest = "on";

But nobody is saying how to get the code without registering the domain. I have a google adsense account but it is not registered for a website, it is registered for google admobs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe google_adtest is now redundant and from a time when it was not necessary to whitelist domains. However, I suppose you could white-list any arbitrary domain and then use that ad code for a local host setup. What is your aim? If it is to test ad serving, then you might be better suited deploying to a staging version on your live domain; hidden from real-world users, but still reflecting a production environment.